# gRPC how to stream a huge string

Tags: c#, .net-core, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto

I got a c# grpc service which can get a request to get a setting in a form of a SINGLE json string which can be very large and I don't want to send it all at once. However, the string can not be processed before it arrives completely.

I know there's an option to use the `stream` keyword in the protobuf and read the string as it arrives, instead of sending it as a whole.

I have only found examples of receiving several items from a stream (with `asyncServerStreamingCall.ResponseStream.MoveNext()`), However I don't know how to stream a single string.

My questions are:

1. Is streaming a correct approach for this situation where you need to stream only a single object (string in this case), and CANT process it before it arrives completely?
2. How do I stream and receive a string like that (from both server and client sides)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Streaming in gRPC is, as you mentioned, talking about sending multiple discreet operations on a single open channel. Whether unary or streaming, individual messages in gRPC must be received and decided in their entirety - there isn't a concept of an open byte-stream. Instead, you would need to send multiple messages that each contain some fragment of the payload, presumably just in a `bytes` field, and send the large payload split over some number of such messages. The receiver would need to combine them, perhaps appending to a file, or similar, if it will be inconveniently large for in-memory storage.

Comment: When splitting the string like that to bytes and sending it over several messages, does the order of messages guaranteed to be consecutive, meaning I can just append everything as it arrives or do I need to send some index or something as well and start saving everything which comes out of order?

Comment: @Yonatan I *believe* the answer is "yes, order is maintained in gRPC streams"; as in, I'm 99.5% sure, but: if you're worried, an integer incrementing field as a panic button would be trivial to add

Comment: Another question if I may.. what happens if i declare a stream in the proto file on a server response, but in the server code just return Task.FromResult(res) like its not a stream, instead of using await responseStream.WriteAsync(response)? Will it work the same as if there wasn't a "stream" keyword, or will it break something?

Comment: @YonatanNir what is `res` in that example? No, I don't think that will work "as is", but: what are you trying to simplify here? In part, because I may know better ways to try to do it if I understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: i already have an implementation without the stream keyword. The res is some value for example an int. The question is if adding the stream keyword but not changing anything else is ok and just won't do anything, or will it break the current implementation?

Comment: @Yonatan no, you can't just add the stream keyword. That isn't how it works. You need to actually provide each individual fragment to the stream